# Can't boot into home screen

Tags: boot, initramfs

I don't know what happened, but I cannot boot into my home screen. Instead I get this screen.

[image: error screen]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Did you modify /etc/fstab by any chance?

Comment: It's working now I ran fsck /dev/sda1 and it basically ran for 2 hrs and after that i was able to boot into home.